# Showing that the subgroup of square of elements of a group G is normal.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let G be a group. If $H=\left \{ g^{2}:g \in G \right \}$ is a subgroup of G, prove that it is a normal subgroup of G.

I am able to utilise the basic definition to begin this question but it doesn't seem to lead to anything fruitful.

Hints are appreciated.

Comment: Normal means $xHx^{-1}=H$ for all $x\in G$. What is $x\{g^2:g\in G\}x^{-1}$? What are its elements?

Comment: The elements are $xg^{2}x^{-1}$ in $xHx^{-1}$

Comment: And by closure, we are done.

Comment: We cannot conclude $xg^2x^{-1}$ is an element of $H$ just from the fact that $H$ is closed under multiplication, because $x$ is not generally an element of $H$. Instead, you must notice $xg^2x^{-1}=(xgx^{-1})^2$ (because conjugation by $x$ is an automorphism), and since $(xgx^{-1})^2$ is a square it must be in $H$ by definition.

Comment: In fact, the conclusion that $H=\{g^2:g\in G\}$ is a normal *subset* of $G$ follows independently of whether or not $H$ is a subgroup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A subgroup is normal if $a^{-1}Ha = H$ for all $a$ in $G$. Note that if $h \in H,$ then $h = g^2$ so that $$a^{-1}ha = a^{-1}g^2a = a^{-1}gga = a^{-1}gaa^{-1}ga = (a^{-1}ga)^2 \in H$$

So the subgroup is normal.

Comment: My initial attempt was similar to yours up till the the third equality.

Comment: Yeah you just need to insert the $aa^{-1}$ term in the middle to see that it's a square element.